# Sql query inner join with LIKE and WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. One called `tbl_issue` one called `tbl_user`. `tbl_issue` has a field called issue list that contains issues column such as `id`, `uid` (user id), `pid` (project id) etc. `tbl_user` on the other hand has a table it holds user details like `id` (that is user id), `u_name` (that is user name), `p_list` (projects id) etc.

I want to show user name according to `uid` (user id)
code is:

```
SELECT tbl_issue.id, tbl_issue.pid, tbl_issue.uid, tbl_user.u_name 
FROM tbl_issue 
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_issue.uid LIKE Concat('%',tbl_user.id,'%')
WHERE uid = $uid;
```

code example:

```
SELECT tbl_issue.id, tbl_issue.pid, tbl_issue.uid, tbl_user.u_name
FROM tbl_issue 
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_issue.uid LIKE '%7%'
WHERE uid = '7'`
```

here `uid=7` and `tbl_user.id =7` is `Lokesh Sharma`

this code is given output

```
id  pid  uid  u_name
14  4    7    admin
14  4    7    ramesh
14  4    7    hemant
14  4    7    lokesh
17  3    7    ravi
17  3    7    lokesh
```

I want to result like

```
14  4    7    lokesh
15  4    7    lokesh
16  5    7    lokesh
17  5    7    lokesh
18  3    7    lokesh
19  3    7    lokesh
```

please help and suggest right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to join `tbl_user` to `tbl_issue` using `LIKE`. What is wrong with just `tbl_issue.uid = tbl_user.id`?

And your `ON` condition is pointed on a value, which is either a variable or 7, instead of the column of `tbl_user`.

```
SELECT a.id, a.pid, b.id, b.u_name
    FROM tbl_issue a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_user b ON a.uid = b.id
    WHERE b.id = 7
```

Comment: it showing all data that contain 7. it's a problem. i want only u_name which id = 7

Comment: @HemantSingh - that is what my answer will try to provide to you. Test it.

Comment: Thanx #Logan Wayne

Comment: if i'll use filter in my table  than table show all data not filtered data